# Akka Streams: StreamDetachedException when offering to a QueueSource

Tags: java, akka, akka-stream

We have a `DownloadFileFlow` class which uses `Akka Streams` & `Akka Http` for downloading files from difference domains; Sometimes (~50%) in offering to the `QueueSource` we encounter `StreamDetachedException` error immediately:

```
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: akka.stream.StreamDetachedException: Stage with GraphStageLogic akka.stream.impl.QueueSource$$anon$1-queueSource stopped before async invocation was processed
   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:332)
   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniAcceptNow(CompletableFuture.java:747)
   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniAcceptStage(CompletableFuture.java:735)
   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenAcceptAsync(CompletableFuture.java:2186)
   at scala.concurrent.java8.FuturesConvertersImpl$CF.thenAccept(FutureConvertersImpl.scala:29)
   at scala.concurrent.java8.FuturesConvertersImpl$CF.thenAccept(FutureConvertersImpl.scala:18)
   at x.y.z.DownloadFileFlow.offer(DownloadFileFlow.java:60)
```

We have no clue what could be the cause of the error, but there is a `postStop` method in `akka.stream.impl.QueueSource`, which we doubt it, but don't know the cause of stop:

```
override def postStop(): Unit = {
  val exception = new StreamDetachedException()
  completion.tryFailure(exception)
}
```

Could the reason for this problem be that we have a resource leak somewhere? For example not consuming the http-response-entity in some cases?

1. SourceQueue reference:

```
AtomicReference<SourceQueueWithComplete<FileDownloadEnvelope>> queueRef = new AtomicReference<>()
```

2. Definition:

```
RestartSource.onFailuresWithBackoff(
     RestartSettings.create(props.getRecoverMinBackOff(), props.getRecoverMaxBackOff(), RANDOM_FACTOR),
        () -> Source.<FileDownloadEnvelope>queue(props.getBufferSize(), OverflowStrategy.backpressure(), props.getMaxConcurrentOffers())
            .filter(this::checkExpiration)
            .map(x -> Pair.create(createContext(x), x))
            .flatMapConcat(this::authIfNeeded)
            .mapAsyncUnordered(props.getParallelism(), this::process)
            .map(this::reply)
            .mapMaterializedValue(x -> {
                this.queueRef.set(x);
                return x;
            }))
    .runWith(Sink.ignore(), actorSystem);
```

3. Access (`offer` method):

```
public void offer(FileDownloadEnvelope envelope) {
    queueRef.get().offer(envelope)
        .thenAccept(x -> {
            if (!x.isEnqueued())
                replyError(envelope);
        }).exceptionally(e -> { // StreamDetachedException catched here
            replyError(envelope);
            return null;
        });
}
```

Akka Http Props:

```
akka.http.host-connection-pool.min-connections: "10"
akka.http.host-connection-pool.max-connections: "2000"
akka.http.host-connection-pool.max-open-requests: "4096"
akka.http.host-connection-pool.max-retries: "0"
akka.http.host-connection-pool.client.connecting-timeout: 2s
akka.http.host-connection-pool.client.idle-timeout: 5s
```

Stream props:

```
BUFFER-SIZE: "2000"
MAX-CONCURRENT-OFFERS: "2000"
PARALLELISM: "70"
RECOVER-MIN-BACK-OFF: 100ms
RECOVER-MAX-BACK-OFF: 500ms
```

And we are using `akka & akka-stream: 2.6.19` & `akka-http: 10.2.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of error was an issue in handling of a specific error in `process` method. An exception was thrown in this case, and apparently, throwing exception causes dropping all existing elements from the queue with `StreamDetachedException reason.

```
.exceptionally(e -> {
    // ...
    else if (e.getCause() instanceof FooException) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e); // cause
    }
    // ....
});
```

Returning error object instead of throwing exception, resolved the issue.